# Meaning of the word "shutface"

Tags: meaning, nouns

I have a question concerning the location of the vehicle safety certification label in a certain car. The corresponding user's manual says: "A vehicle safety certification label is attached to the rear shutface of the driver' s door".

I am not a native speaker of English and hence my question - what is the rear shutface, exactly. Is this a part of the door or the body of the car (i.e. the B pillar). If this is affixed to the doors then where exactly - in plain English? Is this the part of the doors that is "hidden" when the doors are closed - i.e. the width of the doors?

Comment: I've never heard the word before (but that's irrelevant because it is obviously a word that people use). BUt it sounds sort of rude like 'Shut yer facehole'.

Comment: Off-topic I suppose: the OED has *shut-face* from 1631, presumued mean "an air of mystery".

Comment: I thought it was just a typo :)

Answer (score 10):

It's a domain-specific "neologism" (probably not widely used even there, and possibly a complete "one-off" in the context you found).

It means the flat part of the door *between the inner and outer faces, **opposite** the hinge side* (i.e. - the bit you can only see when the car door is open).

[image] [image]

In practice, such stickers may also be positioned on the car *body* rather than the door itself (lining up with the ***hinge*** side of the door, as in the second picture). Since the usage is a neologism, I see no reason to suppose "shutface" specifically and only means the one on the *door*. So it really just means *a facing edge which isn't visible when the door is closed*.

Comment: Domain-specific, but [not one-off](http://www.davehardwick.co.uk/price-lists/price-list-ah100/door-shut-face-rh-lh-later.html)

Comment: @Andrew: Well, I won't change my answer text, because to all intents and purposes it might as well be a one-off for all the currency it has. It's also worth pointing out that in your link ***shut face*** is a *two-word "compound noun" usage.*

Comment: Shut-face also refers to a particular orientation of a golf club during a swing, but that is clearly not in play for this question. My mechanic in PA, USA recognizes shut-face as that part of a car.

Comment: @ScotM: If we're going to include *hyphenated* versions, here's a reference to [*the windshield **frame** shut-face*](http://www.google.com/patents/US6036256) where it seems to mean the "facing edge" of the *surrounding frame*, rather than the internal component (windshield, door, whatever).

Comment: The auto industry seems to like that expression, my mechanic cares nothing about the spelling ;-).

Comment: @ScotM: Let's not forget this is in a ***User*** manual - and I note it specifically says the ***rear** shutface*. You might by implication think the [forward shutface](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=%22forward+shutface%22&aq=f&aqi=g5g-z1g4&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&gws_rd=ssl) would be on the opposite side of the door (if the word always applied to a face on the *door*, rather than *or frame*). But both of the items in that link are for ***faces on the door frame***, so I think my "in practice" point in the answer is now effectively unassailable.

Comment: I agree, @FumbleFingers, the "shut face" seems to be one of **six** "interfacing surfaces" perpendicular to the exterior door surface, which disappear when the door is closed: "Bottom" toward the road, "Front" toward the front of the car and hinges, "Back" toward the back of the car and latch. It seems to refer to the frame surface and/or the door surface. I have not yet found the single word construction of the OP, which tends to support your "one-off" conclusion for *shutface*.

Comment: @ScotM: ***Six?*** Assuming a *rectangular* door (or any other "removable/openable thing that fits into a frame"), surely there would be ***eight*** potential "shutfaces"? (internal/external faces on top, bottom, and each side). But it would be a bit awkward to actually read the tyre pressure sticker/label in some of those positions.

Comment: In most car doors, the "top" is a flush compression fit between the gasket on the frame and the exterior car door or window surface, with the perpendicular surface disappearing at the top :-)

Comment: Your second photo is of the frame shutface, not the door shutface.

Comment: @Andrew: I know. It took me a while to find that second picture - which I only added later; I looked for but couldn't find one first time around. When I added the second one (prompted by the comments here) I amended the text *under* the pictures to specifically point out the difference (I felt it deserved to be recognised, since it had been a matter of some considerable trial and tribulation for me! :)

Comment: Hi Fumble Fingers. U R Very helpful but... I am preparing a sworn translation for the court in the case against a personthat changed said placard and placed it somewhere else in the car (not on the shutface). if I understand correctly from the v. interesting discussion, this phrase may refer to the doors or the door frame. Otherwise it does not specifically says the door OR the frame. It is either this or that. Am I correct? I do not want to flog a dead horse but please understand the position I am in. So, in your opinion - what should I write? the translation may not be unclear.

Comment: @Marceli_2015: IANAL, but I really can't see how anyone could expect to get away with wasting the court's time arguing about the meaning of limited-currency trade-specific jargon. Your cited context is crystal clear in terms of identifying the ***rear** shutface of the **driver's door***. To most Anglophones (indeed, speakers of *any* language) there isn't a single established term for *any of the edges on or around a closure which become visible only when opened*, but that really shouldn't be a problem where the *context* is so clear.

Answer (score 0):

“Shutface” is a term invented by the automotive industry to describe the surface area which connects the inside and the outside of the vehicle. It has a variety of applications depending on which volumes need to be closed or connected.